# Spring Boot - Create a Deployable War File - Warning

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, spring-webflux, war, spring-webclient

In the Spring Boot documentation there is a warning (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle//#howto.traditional-deployment.war):

> Because Spring WebFlux does not strictly depend on the servlet API and applications are deployed by default on an embedded Reactor Netty server, War deployment is not supported for WebFlux applications.

Is this warning valid if i use the maven dependency "spring-boot-starter-webflux" only for using WebClient? I don't want to implement reactive web application with Spring Webflux, just use WebClient to make rest request on an external service.

I have implement a non reactive web application with maven dependency "spring-boot-starter-webflux" to use WebClient and no problem for me, just asking if the warning in Spring Boot documentation is a problem for me.

Comment: It doesn't seem that you're building a web app, so you wouldn't distribute it as a War anyway, and it should be irrelevant in your case. btw, why you want to add dependency to `spring-boot-starter-webflux` instead of `web-client` directly?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov the `WebClient` class lives in the webflux dependency. Adding the webflux starter is a good choice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning only applies to Spring WebFlux server applications. If you're using `WebClient` in a Spring MVC application deployed as a WAR this shouldn't affect your application.